# MATLAB how to write a for loop with 2 conditions, one is "==", the other is "~="?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to write an S-Function in Simulink, with the inputs "t" for time, and "LIBs" for the amount of material entering the system. There are 2 outputs. The idea is like this in Simulink.
[Simulink model concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR7D1.png)

What I want to do is that, at a certain time iteration, the input "LIBs" goes to a different output. But during the iteration, there are some special points at which I don't want the input to go to any output.

The code is like this:

MATLAB

```
function [Batts_Spent, Batts_N_Spent] = BattsL6Y(t, LIBs)
for t = 2011:6:2035 
    if t ~= 2005:10:2035
        Batts_Spent = LIBs;
    end
end
for t = 2015:10:2035 
    if t ~= 2005:6:2035
        Batts_N_Spent = LIBs;
    end
end
for t = 2011:6:2035 
    if t == 2015:10:2035
        Batts_Spent = LIBs;
    end
end
end
```

I am sure that this code is not correct, but I don't know how to write it correctly.

And also, even if I have several input and output ports, the S-Function block in the Simulink project still remains only one input and output port. Should I change it to a MATLAB Function block?

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output is. Could you devise a simple example set of input los and corresponding outputs to demonstrate? Right now your code is meaningless because you overwrite the same variable over and over again in the loops.

Comment: I added a figure showing the concept of this Simulink model. I am sorry that I could only add the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `t` is an input parameter, which makes it look like the function is called for each value of t. Then you have a loop iterating over all values of `t`. Considering your image, you don't need a loop at all. You can use `if` in combination with `mod`. For example:

```
function [Batts_Spent, Batts_N_Spent] = BattsL6Y(t, LIBs)
if mod(t-2005,6)==0 && t>=2005
  Batts_Spent = LIBs;
end
end
```

This is only "Every 6th time the value of LIBs will be assigned to the first output". This isn't a finished solution but should be sufficient to get you started. You need a second if like this for the other output.